# prometheus many-many relationship for cronjobs

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have an expr , but i'm getting many-many relationship, I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
expr: |
  label_replace(
    label_replace(
      max(
        kube_job_status_start_time
        * ON(job_name) GROUP_RIGHT()
        kube_job_labels{label_cronjob!=""}
      ) BY (job_name, label_cronjob)
      == ON(label_cronjob) GROUP_LEFT()
      max(
        kube_job_status_start_time
        * ON(job_name) GROUP_RIGHT()
        kube_job_labels{label_cronjob!=""}
      ) BY (label_cronjob),
      "job", "$1", "job_name", "(.+)"),
    "cronjob", "$1", "label_cronjob", "(.+)")
```

Error:

> Error executing query: found duplicate series for the match group
> {job_name="es-28121280"} on the left hand-side of the operation:
> [{**name**="kube_job_status_start_time",
> instance="xxxxxxxxxxx.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com:443",
> job="kube-state-metrics-eks23", job_name="es-28121280",
> namespace="jobs-ca"}, {**name**="kube_job_status_start_time",
> instance="xxxxxxxxxxxx.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com:443",
> job="kube-state-metric-eks23", job_name="es-28121280",
> namespace="jobs-au"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching
> labels must be unique on one side

Comment: Have you tried debugging your query? Based on my assumption, problem lies in statement inside your `max by` functions.